# Android- two dependency libraries make conflicts,

Tags: android

I need to use two libraries for my app as dependencies. One is for Streaming the CCTV cameras and the SDK is provided by the Company that helps in viewing their cameras via P2P connection. I need to add another library for onvif streaming.

If I add any lib, for example, `com.github.pedroSG94.vlc-example-streamplayer:pedrovlc:2.5.14` to your demo project in android studio

```
 implementation 'com.github.pedroSG94.vlc-example-streamplayer:pedrovlc:2.5.14'
```

Then although the app compiles but will report error like this

```
No implementation found for boolean com.company.NetSDK.INetSDK.Init(com.company.NetSDK.CB_fDisConnect) (tried Java_com_company_NetSDK_INetSDK_Init and Java_com_company_NetSDK_INetSDK_Init__Lcom_company_NetSDK_CB_1fDisConnect_2)
2019-06-02 12:25:13.011 15075-15075/com.astrolabetech.iremote E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.astrolabetech.iremote, PID: 15075
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for boolean com.company.NetSDK.INetSDK.Init(com.company.NetSDK.CB_fDisConnect) (tried Java_com_company_NetSDK_INetSDK_Init and Java_com_company_NetSDK_INetSDK_Init__Lcom_company_NetSDK_CB_1fDisConnect_2)
        at com.company.NetSDK.INetSDK.Init(Native Method)
        at com.astrolabetech.common.NetSDKLib.init(NetSDKLib.java:51)
```

Here `com.company.NetSDK.INetSDK.Init` is from the SDK provided by the camera company.

I tried multiple libraries that can show stream from the ONVIF URI and get this issue when the app has the NETSDK as along with it. If I remove the NETSDK or the streamplayer:pedrovlc lib the app will work.

How can this issue be solved?

## Edits:

The uncompressed APK contains the libs folder as below

[image: uncomprresed apk lib folder]

The libs are from the SDK module's JniLibs folder

[image]

Comment: Share more of your Stack Trace and your Proguard configuration

Comment: It would also help to see you complete build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have the 64bit version of the needed libraries. So you can solve your issue by removing the 64-bit lib folders from your build, or set ABI properties to package only 32-bit architectures.

Reason: While installing apps on Android, inside the "lib" folder of the APK file (you can see the folders by unzipping the file), devices search for folders of native libraries like armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64. So, if the has an arm64-v8a folder with missing "lib" folders, the libraries will not be installed from another folder and will be missing. So your app has to provide the full set of your libraries for each architecture, which is why it is not able to find "boolean".

Comment: So It works when no other 64 bit libs are used , but when I add this other lib that has 64 bit libs than the app will cause these issues?

Comment: my uncompressed apk has the lib folder with armeabi sub-folder only https://imgur.com/a/JjNoFyN

Comment: The SDK module contains JniLibs as shown in this image https://imgur.com/a/MywlhB7